# How to generate OS agnostic file hash in python?

Tags: python, file, hash, operating-system

I am trying to hash a file, using hashlib library in python, by reading its contents as binary chunks of 4096B.

The issue is that it generates different hash for the same file on Windows and Mac.

What is more interesting is that the file is present in a git repo and when pushed to a remote server from Windows and Mac, it generates different hashes for the two scenarios.

I understand that there is an issue with the line endings in Windows being '\r\n' and in Mac '\n'.

This is the code that we had below that generated different hashes.

```
def get_file_hash(file_path: str) -> str:
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()
```

As a quick fix we replaced '\r\n' by '\n'

```
def get_file_hash(file_path: str) -> str:
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        for chunk in f.readlines():
            encoded_chunk = chunk.encode("utf-8").replace(b"\r\n", b"\n")
            print(encoded_chunk)
            hash_md5.update(encoded_chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()
```

Is this a robust way to do this?

Comment: Read the file as binary and hash the `bytes` rather than the `str`, perhaps? (Assuming that the underlying files actually are identical...)

Comment: It's robust as long as there's isn't a `'\r\n'` in the file that isn't a line ending — like the code in your "quick fix".

Comment: Don't try and "fix" newlines. Read the files in binary mode and hash the bytes. If they different then they're different. The fact that they're different because of line endings is irrelevant. It's certainly possible and wise to transfer files in a way that preserves whatever line endings are present.

Comment: @kng have you had any issues with the above approach after all these years? have you discovered a more robust way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are hashing text files.
Try opening them in text mode like this, then encoding each line before updating the hash:

```
import hashlib

def get_file_hash(file_path: str) -> str:
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file_path, "rt") as f:
        for line in f.readline():
            hash_md5.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

print(get_file_hash('file.txt'))
```

Python reads newlines as the universal `\n` so this should generate the same hash on any platform.